# How to compare two non-dichotomous categorical variables?

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data, spss

I have a dataset of individuals with one categorical variable of age groups (18-24, 25-35, etc), and another will illness category (7 values in total). If I graph the data I can see obviously much larger values for certain illnesses in certain age-groups, but I am unsure how I can test to see if these are significantly different. For example, in the 45-54 age-group there are much higher rates of psychiatric illness than other the other groups

Is there a best test within SPSS to look for statistical significant differences between the age-groups and illness? Or is it perhaps better to just report on the obvious distribution findings as are seen above?

Comment: I guess 2-way ANOVA is the test you are looking for. Just google how to do it within SPSS and you will the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of data is usually represented in two-way contingency tables, and your hypothesis - that rates of the different illness categories vary by age group - can be tested using a [chi-square test](https://www.simplypsychology.org/chi-square.html).

Comment: Great thank you. I had wondered if this was the correct method and had run it beforehand (with significant results), but I suppose my confusion lies in how to report the findings and see exactly which groups have higher results. I assume the adjusted residual value for each cell will tell me this, but I am unsure how to get a p-value from this?

Comment: This is certainly not the most elegant way but I have conducted the overall chi-square test and, if that was significant, I have ran separate 2x2 chi-square test for every possible combination (hope this is not straight out wrong, I have only needed to do this in very specific circumstances so I haven't dug into it much).